# How to gray out background image without affecting nav bar or text?

Tags: html, css, image, background, navbar

So basically I'm trying to gray out my background image (OldRag.jpg), but keep the nav bar and other text on the home page on top of it and still in color. The code I've pasted has the background image code removed. I've tried all of the different ways of graying out background image in HTML, CSS, and HTML AND CSS, and none of them work correctly. They either gray out the nav bar and text, or they push the nav bar down and the text gets stuck in the image.

index.html

```
<html>
<title>Edited for privacy - Index</title>
<style> 
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #7A991A;  
</style>

    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="Resume.pdf">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="Edited for privacy">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="Edited for privacy">GitHub</a></li>
    </ul>
<br>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<h2><center>Welcome!</center></font></h2>
<p><center>Thanks for checking out my personal website! Please feel
free to browse the content! </center></p>
</body>
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px; "><font color = #FFFFFF>&copy 2014 Edited for privacy</div></font>
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; "><font color = #FFFFFF>Hosted by GitHub</div></font>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css

```
#nav {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You need to close your a:hover, a:active tag in you css but you also need to clarify what you're trying to accomplish. What element in your html is the image applied to? Place some code in for what you have tried so far.

Comment: @bklynM Well I'm just trying to have the image as the background of the whole page. My original code for the image was 
`html{ background: url(OldRag.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I got you correctly.. ..But my suggestion is:

*since it's just a single background image, if you have a photo editor like "photoshop", take it (the image) into the editor and apply an overlay to make it gray (Black&white).

*then apply the css below to the body tag:

```
html { 
      background: url(OldRag.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover; 
      -moz-background-size: cover; 
      -o-background-size: cover;      
      background-size: cover; 
  }
  //EDIT start
#nav { //notice I didn't include your ul tag. as I'm assuming you're having just one in the page with the ID of nav
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 } 
a:link, a:visited {
display: block;
width: 100px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #98bf21;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
 background-color: #7A991A;  
}
 //EDIT end
```

Also, since you already have an external stylesheet, why not take out the extra styling in your "index.html" and put it there.. ..it will help you avoid some repetition.

And please put the navigation menu inside the body tag.

Comment: Ah, that's a really good idea! Also, could you maybe help me with what and how to move the styling from index.html to my stylesheet?

Comment: Oh and the CSS code you posted displays the image super large. It only has the top portion of the image. The way I added the background image before was with this CSS code: `html { 
  background: url(OldRag.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}`

Comment: ok, 1st of all cut everything from within the `<style>` tag and paste in your external css stylesheet. Combining your own code and mine, I've edited my earlier answer to reflect this. Then secondly, I really don't know the size of your image and the exact result you are trying to achieve.. But I'm sure this links might help you out. [ https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/ ] [ https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ ]